# DC blocking capacitor value for 2-12GHz?

Tags: capacitor, rf

I'm working on a simple RF mixer circuit, and having some trouble picking the right DC blocking cap value for 2-12GHz (even higher if possible). Here's the schematic for the front end LNA:
[image: Front end LNA]

C7 and C9 are what's giving me problems, especially C9 since it's part of the bias-T and I definitely want to get that right so Im not pumping 3.3v into the input of the mixer

What I don't understand is that I've seen some people saying not to go >100pF for any frequencies above 100MHz, but meanwhile this circuit is taken directly from the manufacturer's recommended application circuit in the datasheet and it says to use 100pF which seems high, especially for 15GHz.

Is there some equation I can use to figure out the right value? Or is it not as big of a deal as Im thinking it is?

Comment: It probably has less to do about equations and the actual value of capacitance and more to do about the the correlation between parasitic inductance and capacitance of real capacitors. Or the manufacturers know a lot more about their circuit than the people online who are just mentioning rules of thumb.

Comment: The equations for Return Loss are well defined which determine the values you need. Macon chose theirs for a very low cutoff frequency to ~100MHz or so @-15dB to expand the performance of this DC Darlington amp while blocking lower HF noise. DC blocking is not the issue, rather layout and high quality caps with a high SRF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value you choose for a blocking capacitor mainly depends on how low you need your low frequency cut-off to be.

Macom chose 100 pF for their demo circuit in order to obtain a low-frequency cut-off well below 1 GHz.

If you only need a 2-GHz low-frequency cut-off, and (say) you're willing to accept 10 ohms reactance from your blocking capacitor at that frequency, then you could use a capacitor value as low as about 10 pF.

But if you are using common 0201 size multilayer ceramic capacitors as recommended by Macom, the value you choose won't affect the performance at 15 GHz much, because at that frequency the behavior will be dominated by the inductive parasitic behavior. And the parasitic behavior will mainly depend on the package size you choose (0201 for Macom's recommendation), not the capacitor value.
The part recommended by Macom will give about 10 ohms reactance at 8 GHz (and no data for higher frequencies) according to Murata's SimSurfing tool. As shown in the Macom datasheet (comparing the S21 data for the bare chip and the demo circuit) this will reduce the gain of the circuit by a couple of dB.

If that's not acceptable, special "broadband" and "ultra-broadband" capacitors are available. These essentially package a very high-frequency low-value single-layer ceramic capacitor with a higher-value multi-layer capacitor in the same package. These allow you to push the low-frequency cut-off down to the 10's of kHz with a resonant frequency out beyond 20, and in some cases beyond 50, GHz.  But for these parts expect to pay a few dollars each instead of a few cents. Manufacturers include Presidio Components, ATC, Passive Plus, and Knowles Precision Devices.

Comment: Thanks. I just learned better ways to think about a few things, today. And learned about a few current suppliers I might also learn more about, as well. +1

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I'll just stick with the broadband caps until I learn more about cap selection and parasitics and all that